# Procedure or function 'Emp_Update' expects parameter '@EmpId', which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Emp_Update", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId",Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text));
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        Label1.Text = "Employee Update Sucessfull";
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

'Emp_Update' expects parameter '@EmpId', which was not supplied.
How to solve this issue

Comment: can you please explain it more

Comment: Post the actual full exception text, not just the message. Mention what stack is used, the .NET version and the values that caused this error. The code you posted can only work in WebForms. Using `SqlParameter.AddWithValue` is a bad idea because the database driver will determine the type and size of the parameter from the actual value and [can get bothwrong](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwis2IHT1aD4AhWTrYsKHcNZBlIQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dbdelta.com%2Faddwithvalue-is-evil%2F&usg=AOvVaw2RJU8Yk5ipRJaCUJ2JPeZN)

Comment: define your command type is a stored procedure >> cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;